# $\left\|\int_a^b x(t) dt \right\| \leq \int_a^b \left\| x(t) \right\| dt$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, normed-spaces

I have seen this inequality:

$$\left\|\int_a^b x(t) dt \right\| \leq \int_a^b \left\| x(t) \right\| dt$$

How could I prove that it holds for any $x:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, assuming that $x$ is integrable.

I would like to see a prove of this for a general norm, but if it is easier to do it for a particular norm, it would also help me to get a sense of why it is true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of 'integrable'? If it is defined by a limit applied to some sort of sum then you can show its true for finite sums and then pass to the limit.

Comment: This bears a strong similarity to the triangle inequality. Approximating the integral with Riemann Sums and applying the triangle inequality to each sum looks like it should work.

Comment: Searching on Google gave [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012600).

Comment: @robjohn OP is not assuming continuity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The answer only requires Riemann integrability. The question assumed continuity, but the answer only used that to assure integrability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the integral is defined component wise. Hint: There exist $\mathbb R^{n}$ valued simple functions $x_k$ converging pointwise to $x$ with $\|x_k(t)\|' \leq \|x(t)\|'$ for all $t$ where $\|.\|'$ is the Euclidean norm. Now use the fact any norm on $\mathbb R^{n}$ is equivalent to the Euclidean norm and use the triangle inequality for the given norm.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\zeta := \int_a^b x(t)\, dt$. If $\zeta = 0$ the claim is trivial.
Assume $\zeta \neq 0$. It holds that
$$
|\zeta|^2 = \zeta \cdot \int_a^b x(t)\, dt = \int_a^b \zeta\cdot x(t)\, dt
\leq \int_a^b |\zeta\cdot x(t)|\, dt
\leq \int_a^b |\zeta|\, |x(t)|\, dt
= |\zeta| \int_a^b |x(t)|\, dt
$$
and the claim follows.

Edit: here $|\cdot|$ denotes the standard Euclidean norm.
For a general norm, you can prove first the inequality for simple functions.
Assume that
$$
x(t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \chi_{I_i}(t) \, x_i\,.
$$
Then
$$
\left\| \int_a^b x(t)\, dt\right\| = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^N m(I_i)\, x_i\right\|
\leq \sum_{i=1}^N m(I_i)\, \|x_i\| = \int_a^b \|x(t)\|\, dt.
$$

Comment: This works for the Euclidean norm but OP is asking if it works for any norm on $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: You are right. I haven't read the additional requirement.